# How do I mock this Redis ES6 class?

Tags: typescript, express, testing, jestjs, ioredis

I am building an API powered by Express.js, it uses [ioredis](https://github.com/redis/ioredis), it contains an ES6 class for configuring connections to a redis cluster:

```
import { Cluster } from 'ioredis';
import { settings } from '../config';

export class Redis
{
  public cluster: Cluster;

  public isConnected: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    // Get array of rootNodes and default settings for each node
    const { cluster } = settings.redis;
    
    this.cluster = new Cluster(cluster.rootNodes, {
      enableReadyCheck: true,
      redisOptions: cluster.defaults
    });

    this.cluster.on('ready', () => {
      console.log('Redis connection established, ready to receive commands');
      this.isConnected = true;
    });

    this.cluster.on('error', (error) => {
      console.log(`Redis connection error, status is ${this.cluster.status}`);
      console.log(error.message);
    });

    this.cluster.on('close', () => {
      console.log('Redis connection closed');
      this.isConnected = false;
    });

    this.cluster.on('reconnecting', () => {
      console.log('Reconnecting to redis cluster...');
    });
  }
}

export const redis = new Redis();
```

This class is used by a method which serves an API endpoint (simplified for brevity):

```
import { redis } from '../services/Redis';
...

async load(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const data = <LoadGameRequest>req.params;
  const gameID = data.gameId;

  if (! redis.isConnected) {
    throw new Error(`Redis connection is not established, status is ${redis.cluster.status}.`);
  }
  
  const game = await redis.cluster.get(gameID);
  if (game !== 'OK') {
    throw new Error('Result not OK. Unable to retrieve saved game.');
  }
  ...
  return res.status(200).send(game)
}
```

I want to implement tests, using [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) and jest/ts-jest. I have written a test for the endpoint above:

```
import supertest from 'supertest';
import app from '../app'; // the express app

describe('Test Game Load', () => {
  test('It should return OK response', done => {
    supertest(app).get('/api/load?gameId=1234').then(async (response) => {
      expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
      await done();
    });
  });
});
```

How do I mock my `Redis` class within this context? I have tried using `ioredis-mock`, but unfortunately I am a bit lost as to how exactly I replace the dependency in my app with the mocked version. I also tried to follow jest's documentation, but unfortunately I could not make an informed decision as to which path to follow.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thank you.